# How do i solve these variations of the 0-1 knapsack algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

The knapsack can carry a maximum weight , say max_wt ; has n items with a given weight`wt[]` and a value`val[]`.I have two questions ( both seperate from each other ) :

- What is the maximum value we can carry if there was a second limit to the volume we could carry , vol[ ] ?
- What are the  number of ways to carry a total of exactly z(< n) items such that their sum of values is divisible by a number , say 8 ?

**My Attempt**

- For the first question i refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827600/multiple-constraint-knapsack-problem) stackoverflow post , but the only answer i could understand was one where the two constraints were merged ,but the run time complexity of that would be quite big i guess...what i was thinking was making a `dp[i][j][k]` , where i is the number of items selected , j is the max-wt selected at that point , k is the max-vol selected at that point and then my core of the code looked like 
  `for(i=0 ; i < n ; i++) \\ n is no. of items
  for(j=0 ; j < n ; j++) 
     for(k=0 ; k < n ; k++)
     dp[i][j][k] = max( dp[i-1][j][k] , val[i] + dp[i-1][j-wt[j]][k-vol[k]]) ;`
  , this seems alright , but gives me wrong answer ... i cant guess why :(
- I can't start to think of the second problem, my friend did it by taking three states dp[i][j][k] where i and j are just same as first question(the usual ones) while 'k' keeps track of the total items selected , this idea isnt getting in my head . Plus , what will a state store , it usually stores max value possible till given state in classical knapsack problems , here i guess a state will store total combinations divisible by 8 till that state , but i cant convert this into code .

p.s please try providing a solution with bottom up approach to the second question , i am very new to dynamic programming . ;)

Comment: _What is the maximum number of ways..._ - do you mean just the number of ways? If not, what does maximum refer to?

Comment: "such that their sum is divisible by a number" - sum of what? the weight/volume or something else?

Comment: sorry , i get the question is unclear , here's the question again in its entirity : given var[ ] , wt[ ] of n items , how do we select exactly z( < n) for our knapsack such that the value is divisible by a number (here 8 ) , it is seperate from the other question and has no volume ...thanks

Comment: @DanielRodriguez sum of value , just the value there is no volume constraint for the second question

Comment: @Gassa i worded it wrongly..i meant just the number of ways...thank you for picking that out

Comment: And then there's `val[]` vs `vol[]`...People here won't be very inclined to help you if you can't present the problem better than this.

Comment: @TonyK `vol[ ]` is array of volume of first n elements , `val[ ]` is array of value of first n elements , `wt[ ]` is array of weight of first n elements .Ask any other doubt if you have....and pls give the question a shot .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two-dimensional knapsack problem

- let `n` be the number of items
- let `val[i]` be the value of the `i`-th item
- let `w[i]` be the weight of the `i`-th item
- let `v[i]` be the volume of `i`-th item
- let `T[i,j,k]` be the best value out of the first `i` items and having **exactly** weight `j` and volume `k`. `T` can be defined in some other way but this definition gives a short formula.

Finding best value

- `T[0,j,k] = 0`
- `T[i,j,k] = T[i-1,j,k]`, when `j<w[i]` or `k<v[i]`, otherwise:
- `T[i,j,k] = max( T[i-1,j,k] , T[i-1,j-w[i],k-i] + val[i] )`
- best possible value would be max `T[n,j,k]` for all j and k

Implementation notes

- initialize base cases first for all `j` and `k`
- loop `i` from 1 to n and be consistent with 1-based arrays indexes
- loop `j` from 1 to max possible weight which is the sum of all weights, e.g. `w[1]+w[2]+...w[n]`
- loop `k` from 1 to max possible volume

Counting number of ways to get an exact value with an exact number of items

- let `S[i,j,k,l]` be the number of ways in which the first `i` items can be arranged with exactly weight `j`, value `k`, and `l` items.
- `S[0,j,k,l] = 0`, except `S[0,0,0,0] = 1`
- `S[i,j,k,l] = S[i-1,j,k,l] + S[i-1,j-w[i],k-val[i],l-1]`
- number of ways to get exactly value `y` using exactly `z` items is the sum of `T[n,j,y,z]` for all `j`

Observations

There are many ways to look at these problems and to define the states T and S. This is but one of them. Implementations can also differ. The thumb-rule for dimensions is that another constraint in the sack or dimension in the items means another dimension in the formula. The thumb-rule for counting ways is that you add up instead of finding max.

Comment: Call "the number ... (e.g. 8)" for the second question q.  You can save memory in the second DP by restricting `k` to the range 0 .. q-1 and doing all arithmetic operations on `k` mod q.

Comment: Nice answer...could you please explain the last line though ...I don't understand how `S[i,j,k,l] = S[i-1,j,k,l] + S[i-1,j-w[i],k-val[i],l-1]`  counts the total number of ways....from my understanding ,you made s[0,0,0,0] equal to 1 so that whenever that state is reached , the number of count is increased , but I am not sure if I am right . Plus what is the difference between `T[ ]` and `S[ ]` , there was no mention of `T[ ]` for second problem... 

Comment: `S[i,j,k,l]` either has the `i`-th item or it doesn't. The number of ways to get to state (i,j,k,l) is the number of ways to get there using the `i`-th item plus the number of ways to get there not using the `i`-th item.
The counting problem doesn't care about maximizing value (T), just the number of ways to get an specific value, that's why value is a dimension.